# Is Multitasking Enabled iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, multitasking

Please could you tell me how I could find out if multitasking is enabled on the iPhone. I am using Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty much straight out of Apple's documentation:

```
UIDevice* device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
BOOL backgroundSupported = NO;
if ([device respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)])
    backgroundSupported = device.multitaskingSupported;
return backgroundSupported;
```

Comment: Thanks but that tells you if its supported, I need to know if its enabled.

Comment: Uh... it's always enabled if it's supported.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, I must be implementing it wrong. I have tested it on an iTouch 2g and it says that multitasking is supported, but it isnt enabled on my itouch? Im running iOS4.1